# How to get object index?

Tags: iphone, ios, indexing, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How can I get my object index? I have a dictionary containing arrays and inside the arrays i have multiple dictionary.

My data structure(eg):

> Student ------ NSDictionary
>
> > ```
> >    Item 0 ------ NSArray<br>
> >           Name ----- Grace<br>
> >           Age ----- 20<br>
> >    Item 1 ------ NSArray<br>
> >           Name ----- Anne<br>
> >           Age ----- 21<br>
> > ```

So for example, I have the value of the name, Grace, and I want to get the value of the object index array (in this case, item 0). How can I do so?

I've used the indexOfObject however the results I got back is 2147483647, which i think it means nsnotfound. So i think it doesnt work for this case.

This are my codes:

```
NSMutableDictionary* namevalue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
namevalue = [somedict objectForKey:@"Name"];              
int arryindex;
arryindex = [somearray indexOfObject:namevalue];                
NSLog(@"Array Index:%i", arryindex);
```

Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for a way to find object index in NSDictionary based on the value of property that object has, right?
E.g. your `students` dictionary has a student with name `Grace` and you would like to know at which index the student object with name `Grace` is stored...

If above is true, here's my (incomplete and rough) solution which works **only** for objects with `NSString` properties, but once you get the idea below, I think you'll be able to modify code to match your needs.

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfObjectWithPropertyValue:(id)value inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSInteger objectIndex = 0;
    unsigned int outCount, i;

    for (id key in dict) {
        id objForKey = [dict objectForKey:key];
        Class lender = [objForKey class];

        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(lender, &outCount);

        for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];
            id v = [objForKey valueForKey:[NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            if ([v isKindOfClass:[value class]] && [v isEqual:value]) {
                return objectIndex; 
            }
        }
        objectIndex++;
    }

    return NSNotFound; // i.e. NSIntegerMax
}
```

and don't forget to include runtime header:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

My code may and probably have some issues:

- the most obvious `isEqual:` method which needs to compare properties' values.
- above code does not cover a situation when there are many objects with same value (like many students with the same name!)
- ???

I hope my "answer" will make it easier for you to implement what you need.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you forgot to include the creation of `somedict` and `somearray`. The problem may be there.

Also, you don't need to assign `namevalue` an empty dictionary and then the actual dictionary inside the array.

Check this fragment of working code:

```
NSUInteger idx;
NSDictionary *john = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John", @"name", 
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:23], @"age", nil];
NSDictionary *jane = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Jane", @"name", 
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:24], @"age", nil];    
NSArray *students = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:john, jane, nil];
idx = [students indexOfObject:john];
NSLog(@"john is at: %i", idx == NSNotFound ? -1 : idx); /* 0 */
idx = [students indexOfObject:jane];
NSLog(@"jane is at: %i", idx == NSNotFound ? -1 : idx); /* 1 */
```

Now, try with an object not present in the array:

```
NSDictionary *mary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mary", @"name", 
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:22], @"age", nil];        
idx = [students indexOfObject:mary];
NSLog(@"mary is at: %i", idx == NSNotFound ? -1 : idx); /* -1 Not found */
```

And finally with a new object but created as an exact duplicate of an object already present in the array:

```
NSDictionary *maryjane = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Jane", @"name", 
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:24], @"age", nil];            
idx = [students indexOfObject:maryjane];
NSLog(@"maryjane is at: %i", idx == NSNotFound ? -1 : idx); /* 1 */
```

The method `indexOfObject` will use `isEqual:` to compare objects. You can verify that the new object will be considered as equal to the one inside the array:

```
NSLog(@"jane is maryjane? %i", [jane isEqual:maryjane]); /* 1 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply(: somedict is a dictionary with value in my codes. I just add a snippet of the important codes here(: I dont know the "namevalue" of the index array i wanna find as it is according to the user input. That's why i wanna know whether there is a way to retrieve the object index by the"namevalue" (: